# Redrects with special characters in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm setting up redirects for a client in Next.js. We have a configuration like so inside `next.config.js`:

```
{
    source: '/page.aspx:urlstr*',
    destination: 'https://someurl.com/page.aspx:urlstr*',
    permanent: true,
},
```

The actual URLs hitting this will have a long URL string like so:
`page.aspx?woXxJNrRIMKVC109awwTopP+k2NmkvXf+MzijTEc3zIZ3pf4n+Yknq`

This is being URL encoded to be:
`https://someurl.com/page.aspx?woXxJNrRIMKVC109awwTopP%20k2NmkvXf%20MzijTEc3zIZ3pf4n%20Yknq`

The old server hosting these pages at the destination can't handle the URL encoded query string. Is there a way to force Next.js to not parse it?

Comment: If those `+` symbols are actually meant to be `+` and not represent a space, they should be `%2B` in the original URL. In a URL, `+` and `%20` both represent the same thing

Comment: The last `+` doesn't get urlencoded?

Comment: Sorry, typo - it does get encoded. Weirdly on my local machine it converts them to straight spaces, but that might be a Firefox thing

Comment: @Phil - is there any way in Next.js I can control this, like parse the URL before the redirect module catches it? Right now everything that happens is from within Next.js

Comment: Control what? If your requests are malformed because they're not encoded correctly, you'll need to fix it at the source

Comment: These are legacy URLs, so I have no control over their format. Are you saying there's no way to write some kind of middleware between the request coming in and the Next.js redirect code running?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution was in fact to use the Next.js middleware feature:
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware

It's a little buggy though. The docs say to add `middleware.js` to the same level as the pages directory, but you actually need to add `_middleware.js` *inside* the pages directory.

Also the `matches` feature does not seem to work for me at all, so here's my solution:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request) {

    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/page.aspx')) {
        let url = new URL(request.url);
        return NextResponse.redirect(`https://someurl.com${url.pathname}${url.search}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: _"The docs say to add middleware.js to the same level as the pages directory, but you actually need to add _middleware.js inside the pages directory"_ - The docs are for Next.js v12.2.0 onwards, usage of middleware changed in that version. See https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/middleware-upgrade-guide.

Comment: @juliomalves ah good point, thanks